# What is the nonparametric equivalent of the Weighted-Least-Squares-Regression?

Tags: weighted-regression, nonparametric-regression

I am struggling to find the nonparametric equivalent of the WLSR.
In brief, I need a nonparametric regression method which allows to assign different weights to data according to the uncertainty.

I could use the LOWESS function, but in this case the function implements regression weights (for instance, in Matlab the weights are given by a tricube function). I do not know how to add "custom weights", which take into account the standard deviation associated at each point.

Comment: Could you be more specific on what exactly do you need it for? I guess you are not looking for any nonparametric approach that enables you to use weights...

Comment: I need to fit a curve which describes the relationship btw Y and X. Since my data does not meet the assumptions behind the parametric methods, I need a nonparametric regression. The LOWESS is an example. However, I also need to weight data differently, according to the standard deviation (something like the WLSR).

Comment: So use weighted LOWESS...

Comment: LOWESS does not accept custom weights, as far as I know...

Comment: E.g. `loess` function in R does accept them.